# Issues with modifying the editor document in Intellij Plugin development

Tags: intellij-plugin

When I do something like this in a a Writecommand action,
editor.getDocument().insertString(offset, "Sample text");

I guess it is stored in cache and is not updated immediately.
So what can be done to get the update in the very immediate line.
I tried refreshing the Virtualfile synchronisely and asynchronisely, but didnt help.
So what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

To update the file on disk, use `FileDocumentManager.saveDocument()`. To update the PSI for the document, use `PsiDocumentManager.commitDocument()`.